# Is [rules] a useful tag at all?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, burninate-request

I was just looking at [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rules)  and it seems kind of useless to me. It's mostly a collection of all kinds of programming questions where the meaning of the word is very broad.

In some cases a retag would probably be an option:

- Questions regarding `RewriteRule`, which would fit a lot better under [mod-rewite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewite) (of which [rewriterule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rewriterule) is a synonym)
- Questions about validation rules ([validationrules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validationrules))
- Questions about rules engines ([rule-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rule-engine))
- Questions about the Drupal Rules module ([drupal-rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-rules))

Most of the others either refer to a setting called "rules" within an application ([Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905082/multiple-shopping-cart-rules-not-working), [Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702171/outlook-rule-copy-email-to-directory-based-on-content-of-subject)) which wouldn't warrant their own tag, or simply refer to the concept of defining rules in a general sense.

I'm not really aware of how tags like these should be handled (burninate? retag? something else?) but I do think that this tag is rather useless.

Comment: clean-up by retagging/editing/close-voting/deleting.

Comment: Retagged to drupal-rules, mod-rewrite/url-rewriting, magento-rules and form-validation/validationrules where appliccable so far.

Comment: Retagged all [jquery][rules] to jquery-validation where relevant

Comment: So how does this work now? There might be a handful of retaggable questions left but the list went from over 700 to ~485 and I feel like 99% of the remaining questions could just lose the rules tag without losing any meaning at all.

Comment: I strain to see how tagging your question about validationrules in a framework/orm/odm helps you get a decent answer at all and provides anything but noise and minor tags

Comment: Hmm, you may have a point with that.

Comment: If all else is done, flag for help removing the tag wholesale. For best effect, read this post once more first: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191

Answer (score -1):

The term "rules" is also used as a common business requirement that developers often implement using dedicated tools such as:

- IBM JRules
- Red Hat JBoss BRMS (Business Rules Management System)
- Drools (open source)
- etc

The good news is that we already have [business-rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/business-rules) to cover these.