# Burninate [rules] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rules) tag is problematic.  It meets the criteria for burnination:

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Yes it describes the contents, but no it is not unambiguous in regards to what a rule means without adding other more specific tags or otherwise writing out the specifics in the question.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Only when attributed more specifically with other tags. The tag itself is not clear enough.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Potentially, although better context should be added through more meaningful tags. See the rule tag explanation.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No it does not. The meaning is very broad.

These tags should be burninated.  At a minimum these tags could be merged together as an alias.  Related [old request for just the [rules] tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271750/is-rules-a-useful-tag-at-all)

Comment: @ryanyuyu I have clarified by renaming the title. I would say it is an overlapping question in that the question you added looked to start retagging some of the items, but the rule tag is not identified there and probably should be. At a minimum they should be aliased. The problem is that the other request is also 3 years old and was never completed, but based on the comments had the intent to just disassociate en-masse?

Comment: There is also there terrible [rules-of-thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rules-of-thumb) tag.

Comment: +1 Stack Overflow shouldn't have [tag:rules]

Comment: There must be no [rules]!

Comment: Screw the [rules], we got flamethrowers!

Comment: Or, alternatively: Should we [rule] out the [rules]?

Comment: Break the [rules].

Comment: after a quick look at the questions tagged [rule] I see no example where the tag improves the description or would aid in sorting/searching, it is too generic. The presence of a "rule" in a SO question is pretty much axiomatic, may as well have used [question]

Comment: It should be Delteted!! Burninating the country-side, Burninating the peasants. [rules] live in thatched-roof cottages.

Comment: Suggested title: These tags are against the [rules]

Comment: We have the minimum of 20 votes or more. What do we do now?

Comment: New [rules] leave SO tag burninators fuming

Comment: Two years in the burn hopper. I don't have privilege to do it myself or I would. Anyone else?

Comment: @Kara I cleaned that one up and I doubt it will come back

Comment: @MiXT4PE please don't burninate tags without consulting the community. We have a process to follow, there's no need to go for a short cut. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356963/tag-removals-must-be-discussed-and-documented-on-meta. Even though the [rules-of-thumb] had just a few questions, it should go through the burnination process.

Comment: @BhargavRao I see. What do you suggest one should do if a burnination-request (like this one) gets ignored for over 2 years?

Comment: @MiXT4PE None of the burnination requests are ignored. The current backlog is at 9 years of work. If you want to get the process quickened up, start with the ones [that are in progress](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request+status-planned).

Comment: @BhargavRao That is helpful advice. Thank you. Please consider adding explanations about essential processes like this one [to help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=burnination) as it is hard to find a comprehensive description/tutorial on Meta.

Comment: You should always search Meta, @MiXT4PE, there are multiple FAQ posts on how burnination works.